# Reverse for '' not found Django

Tags: django

Can't find the problem

**urls.py**

```py
path("office", views.office, name="office")
```

**views.py**

```py
def office(request):
    offices_list = Office.objects.all()
    context = {'offices_list': offices_list}
    return render(request, "auctions/office.html", context)
```

**template**

```py
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-white " href="{% url 'office' %}">office</a>
</li>
```

Error:
`Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: What is the name of your app? Change `{% url 'office' %}` to `{% url '<app_name>:office' %}`. *Replace `<app_name>` with the name of your app*. Sometimes this clears this error.

Comment: "is not a registered namespace".

Comment: add a namespace in your root urls the same way youve added name in the shown urls

Comment: It appears this error is caused by a *different* line of code in your template, can you share the traceback / full template code?

Comment: it takes me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/office/

Comment: hi all! had to delete the html and rebuild it. works like champ- did rename it though . Thank you all for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

had to delete html page and rebuild it.
worked like charm.
still do not know what the issue was .

Thank you all for your kind contribution !